# CORS erros on Angular FE and fastAPI GCP VM

Tags: angular, fastapi

Hello I get CORS errors trying to reach remote end point.

My remote server is Docker container using fastAPI.
On the server side I added this:

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

In Angular I point to the URL using the HttpInterceptor:

```
const requestUrl = (environment.backend_sll ? 'https' : "https") +"://" + environment.backend_ip + req.url.split('/api')[1];

const newHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
        })

        const extendedReq = req.clone({
            url: requestUrl,
            headers: newHeaders,
            body: {...req.body, user_session_id}
        });

return next.handle(extendedReq).pipe(...
```

When running this setup I get this error:

[image]

I know in Angular you can use the proxy for localhost BUT in production is does not use this proxy file and my remote endpoint is NOT where my hostname is so I get the same errors and a wrong IP address because Angular is using my host name and not the remote IP address.
Because of this I override in the HttpInterceptor the URL and put the IP address I want.

How can I know if the problem is on the FE or the BE? Is there a way to remove CORS rules at all in the FE and BE I know about the security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There is a temp solution for it.

1. Using Chrome/ Firefox extension you can manage the cors errors. This is a temporary fix which will work in development.

   [**allow-cors-access-control**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)